# 'Too many values to unpack' with solvePnPRansac() - Pose Estimation

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to run the code from this tutorial - [Pose Estimation](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_pose/py_pose.html#pose-estimation),

and I get the following error, after calling `solvePnPRansac` function:

`rvecs, tvecs, inliers  = cv2.solvePnPRansac(objp, corners2, mtx, dist)`

> ValueError: too many values to unpack

According the documentation:

> Python: cv2.solvePnPRansac(objectPoints, imagePoints, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs[, rvec[, tvec[, useExtrinsicGuess[, iterationsCount[, reprojectionError[, minInliersCount[, inliers[, flags]]]]]]]]) → rvec, tvec, inliers

Did anyone handle with this issue ?

(Python 2.7 , OpenCV 3b)

Comment: does this code work if you run it under Python 2.7?

Comment: sorry, my bad, its python 2.7 & opencv 3.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The exception says that there are more than 3 values returned. OpenCV3 has changed a lot of method signatures, unfortunately without really documenting it. I inspected the `solvepnp.cpp` and the signature reads:

```
bool cv::solvePnPRansac(InputArray _opoints, InputArray _ipoints,
                    InputArray _cameraMatrix, InputArray _distCoeffs,
                    OutputArray _rvec, OutputArray _tvec, bool useExtrinsicGuess,
                    int iterationsCount, float reprojectionError, double confidence,
                    OutputArray _inliers, int flags)
```

which seems to indicate that nothing has changed. However, in python:

```
solvePnPRansac(...)
solvePnPRansac(objectPoints, imagePoints, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs[, rvec[, tvec[, useExtrinsicGuess[, iterationsCount[, reprojectionError[, confidence[, inliers[, flags]]]]]]]]) 
-> retval, rvec, tvec, inliers
```

So it might help to try out:

```
_, rvecs, tvecs, inliers  = cv2.solvePnPRansac(objp, corners2, mtx, dist)
```

or in case you just want to unpack the last 3 elements:

```
rvecs, tvecs, inliers  = cv2.solvePnPRansac(objp, corners2, mtx, dist)[:-3]
```

Comment: @GuWang return value. When I wrote above it wasn't documented (as I said), I don't know if the situation has changed.

Answer (score 5):

**_, rvecs, tvecs, inliers  = cv2.solvePnPRansac(objp, corners2, mtx, dist)**

worked for me

Answer (score 1):

So I've come across the same issue, and when I print it out, the first value is a True/False value just like it is for the vanilla [solvePnP](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#solvepnp)

I think [solvePnPRansac](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#solvepnpransac) now combines the two outputs, making the result four items: `retval, rvec, tvec, inliers`

Obviously a good bit late for the original asker, but this still took me a good bit to figure out. I'm using Python 2.7.12 with Ubuntu 16.04. I expect the Python version to matter more, I don't know if Python 3.6+ reflects the same behavior.