# OpenCV Error through calibration tutorial (solvePnPRansac)

Tags: python, computer-vision, camera-calibration, opencv3.0, pose-estimation

Can anyone know what is going on with this opencv error ?

```
cv2.error: /home/desktop/OpenCV/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:2294:
 error: (-215) d == 2 && (sizes[0] == 1 || sizes[1] == 1 || 
sizes[0]*sizes[1] == 0) in function create
```

Line code which raise it is :

```
rvecs, tvecs, inliers = cv2.solvePnPRansac(objp, corners2, cameraMatrix, dist)
```

I followed step by step this tutorial:
http://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html

It seems that `cameraMatrix` is incorrect, but why ?

`cameraMatrix` looks like this and seems to be as it would (see [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=solvepnpransac#bool%20solvePnPRansac%28InputArray%20objectPoints,%20InputArray%20imagePoints,%20InputArray%20cameraMatrix,%20InputArray%20distCoeffs,%20OutputArray%20rvec,%20OutputArray%20tvec,%20bool%20useExtrinsicGuess,%20int%20iterationsCount%20,%20float%20reprojectionError%20,%20double%20confidence%20,%20OutputArray%20inliers%20,%20int%20flags%29)):

```
[[ 535.99484574,    0.        ,  334.33388272],
[   0.        ,  535.99541504,  239.81116973],
[   0.        ,    0.        ,    1.        ]]
```

From tutorial :
cameraMatrix – Input camera matrix

[image: cameraMatrix – Input camera matrix =]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your camera matrix is ok.

The error may be caused by *objp* or *corners*.

*objp* must be array of object points in the object coordinate space, 3xN/Nx3 1-channel or 1xN/Nx1 3-channel, where N is the number of points. std::vector of cv::Point3f can be also passed here.

*corners* must be an Array of corresponding image points, 2xN/Nx2 1-channel or 1xN/Nx1 2-channel, where N is the number of points. std::vector of cv::Point2f can be also passed here.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, if you follow the tutorial the declaration of `objp` is not correct - should be like this (`w,h` being your chessboard dimensions):

```
objp = np.zeros((w*h, 1, 3), np.float32) 
objp[:,:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:w,  0:h].T.reshape(-1,1,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Also be careful to change:

```
rvecs, tvecs, inliers  = cv2.solvePnPRansac(objp, corners2, mtx, dist)
```

to either:

```
_, rvecs, tvecs, inliers = cv2.solvePnPRansac(objp, corners2, mtx, dist)
```

or

```
rvecs, tvecs, inliers  = cv2.solvePnPRansac(objp, corners2, mtx, dist)[:-3]
```

if using Python.

See the thread here:
['Too many values to unpack' with solvePnPRansac() - Pose Estimation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28440461/too-many-values-to-unpack-with-solvepnpransac-pose-estimation)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13661857)